# "Don't you speak to me in that tone!" vs. "You don't speak to me in that tone!"

Tags: grammar, imperative-sentences

What's the difference in style, register and usage between

1. Don't you speak to me in that tone!
2. You don't speak to me in that tone!

Comment: The second sounds a bit unnatural. But to come closer to answering your question, it also sounds less severe, less harsh, less angry. Better than either of them would be to omit the *you* altogether: “Don’t speak to me in that tone.” If you’re looking for a softer version, “Please don’t speak to me in that tone,” sounds like someone who is remaining cool, unflappable despite finding their interlocutor’s tone to be unacceptable.

Comment: What makes the second sound unnatural?

Comment: Plenty of people in the UK would say e.g. 'You don't do that in my house!', 'You don't talk like that to my mother!'. It is a statement that the behaviour is unacceptable, as opposed to utterance starting 'Don't...' which are instructions not to behave in the specified way.

Answer (score 3):

"Don't you speak to me in that tone!" is a standard imperative command to somebody, but for the addition of the unusual 'you' after don't. It is very much addressed at the current moment in time, and does not *inherently* indicate that 'that tone' could not be used on another occasion in other circumstances.

"You don't speak to me in that tone!" I understand (and understood as a child) to mean 'You must never speak to me in that tone" (either now, or at any other time) or "Don't you dare speak to me in that tone (ever)."

I've certainly heard both phrases used, usually by a parent and addressed to a child.

"Don't you" and "You don't" are slightly idiomatic elements in both phrases, and could be considered to be intensifiers of the overall imperative tone.

"Don't do X!" is imperative, but could still be a relatively polite warning ("Be careful! Don't do X!"). By contrast, 'Don't you do X!' would be understood to include an implied 'or else you'll be in big trouble/there will be serious repercussions for your failure to obey!'.

And it's worth noting that without an exclamation mark or imperative tone of voice "You don't do X" is a simple statement of fact.

Comment: This structure caused some confusion in my early years as a learner.  I thought ""You don't speak to me in that tone." meant a simple present tense because it seems so for us learners, because it has the same structure as simple present tense sentences, for instance "I don't get up early at weekends. / You don't get up....../He doesn't get up ...." So, we as non-native speakers might not anticipate it is an imperative sentence if there is no context. Is this structure also ambiguous for native speakers if there is no context?

Comment: @yunus. It's an instance where tone of voice would clarify meaning for a native speaker. In written form, the presence or absance of an exclamation mark is required to clarify what's going on. "Don't you ...!" is less ambiguous than 'You don't ...!' because the reversal of the standard word order in a context that is not a question is so idiomatic.